# java runtime.exec: Do not show window for user in case of crash

Tags: java, cmd, runtime, exec

If I run an external Windows application with runtime.exec and it crashes with access violation, a window is shown to the user. This window does not disappear even if you manually destroy the process in java.

Is there a way to say runtime.exec or the process NOT to show any windows to the user?

Please note that I am not able to change the external Windows application so that the occasional crashes cannot be avoided.

Comment: Can we have more information? (Screenshot of the window would be nice). Also, isn´t ProcessBuilder (instead of runtime.exec) the way to go now?

Comment: Unfortunately, the window on my computer is in German. It is a standard window of Windows 7 telling the user that the process is not working and that one can quit the process. Furthermore, it gives some details of the error. Solutions with ProcessBuilder are also welcome.